# ¿Cómo mostrar imagen de um producto dentro de un CRUD en PHP?

Tags: php, crud

Alguien sabrá decirme como puedo mostrar la imagen de un producto en un `CRUD` con `PHP`. En el código consigo mostrar la imagen pero se repite para todos los productos.

Cuando guardo la imagen desde el `form`, se crea un archivo con el mismo `ID` del producto y dentro de este la imagen con su nombre original.

Actualmente tengo esto así:

```
 <?php


    $sql= "SELECT * FROM escurcao WHERE idusuario =  '$idUsuario'";
    $resultado=$mysqli->query($sql) or trigger_error($mysqli->error);
    while($row =mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {


    $id = "18";
    $path = "imagens/img_agencias/img_quartos/".$id;
    if(file_exists($path)){
      $directorio = opendir($path);
         while ($archivo = readdir($directorio)){
    if (!is_dir($archivo)):
    $archivos[filemtime($path.'/'.$archivo)] = $path.'/'.$archivo;
          endif;
       }
            closedir($directorio);

                //Ordenar el array
    ksort($archivos);

                //Buscar la última modificacida
    $ultimaModificada = end($archivos);

         //Compara todas las URLs y solo muestra la última modificada
   foreach ($archivos as $archivo){
   if ($archivo == $ultimaModificada){
   }
  }
  ?>
```

En mi `HTML` tengo la etiqueta `IMG` donde quiero mostrar la imagen de cada  producto.

```
<div class=" col-md-12 margin-bottom">
  <div class="col-md-12 card card2">
    <div class="col-md-3 img-box">

     <img class="img-detalhe" src="<?php echo $archivo; ?>"/>
    </div>

    <div class="  col-md-6 " >
     <div class="row detalhes-titulo">
     <h5 class="card-title"><?php echo $row['escurname'];?></h5>
    </div>
    <div class="row text-detalhe">

     <p class="card-text">DESTINO: <br><?php echo $row['destino'];?></p>
     <p class="card-text">DATA SAÍDA:<br><?php echo $row['data_ida'];?></p>
     <p class="card-text">DATA RETORNO:<br><?php echo $row['data_volta'];?></p>
     <p class="card-text">VALOR:<br><?php echo $row['valor'];?></p>

    </div>

   </div>

   <div class="col-md-3">
   <div class="col-md-6 edita-eliminar-1" style="margin: 50px 0 10px 30px;">
   <a class="fas fa-pencil-alt" href="modificar_escurcao.php?id_escurcao=<?php echo $row['id_escurcao'];?>">
      <span >Editar</span></a>
   </div>

   <div class="col-md-6  edita-eliminar-2" >
        <a href="#" data-href="eliminar_escurcao.php?id_escurcao=<?php echo $row['id_escurcao'];?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete" class="fas fa-trash-alt"  ><span >Excluir</span></a>
   </div>

   </div>
   </div>

   </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consegui exibir las imagenes por cada produto de esta forma:

```
<img class="img-detalhe" src='imagens/img_agencias/img_quartos/<?php echo $row['id_escurcao'];?>/<?php echo $row['nome_img'];?>'/>
```